# Error E0304; Function std::string.insert(), displaying as overloaded function with 9 overloads VS2019

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, compiler-errors, stdstring

```cpp
DisplayMap.insert(i, map[i]);
```

As you can see in the above sample, I've tried to use the insert function, but it keeps displaying the same E0304 Error, which is for an overloaded function. In VS2019, the error details are:

```bash
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list
```

The error says that the arguments don't match because the different overloads have different arguments.
Can you help me solve this error?
Here's my full code if you need it:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include "Data.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, 0);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    int WindowColumns, WindowRows, DisplayBuffer;
    string DisplayMap;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
    WindowColumns = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
    WindowRows = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1;
    cout << WindowColumns << "," << WindowRows;
    DisplayBuffer = WindowColumns * WindowRows;
    for (int i = 0; i < WindowColumns; i++) {
        DisplayMap.insert(i, map[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks In advance.

EDIT:
Data.h here:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <String>
using namespace std;
string savedMap = "                              "
"                              "
"                              "
"                              "
"                              ";
string map = savedMap;
int w = 119, a = 97, s = 115, d = 100;
char key_press;
int myPOS = 35;
int MDPOS = myPOS, ascii_value;
```

Please don't ask me why I use the namespace std in a header file.

Comment: what is the declaration for `map`?

Comment: It is a string that has been defined in a header file, 'Data.h'.

Comment: You have to show exactly how `map` is defined. That declaration is very relevant. The Windows API code is not relevant to this error.

Comment: Let me edit this code and provide code for the Data.h file as well

Comment: Code has been edited, please review again

Comment: [You can see the choices here.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) Which overload are you trying to use?

Comment: The overload that I am trying to use is stated in my code. The first argument is the position I would like to insert the character to. The second argument is that the const char I would like to insert, which is map[i], is a character from the string map itself.

Comment: @IneoSenigupta, That overload doesn't exist in the list. (And to save you the trouble of logging in to see only one standard, [here's the C++20 version](https://i.imgur.com/YSDUqtF.png) with the diffs over the years removed.)

Comment: @everyone Thank you for your help, but I solved this problem, I understood what I had done wrong (natural programmer experience) after a few minutes. The problem was that I had tried to insert a char, while the argument specified a const* char, So, I converted the value to a const* char, and now it doesn't produce any errors. Thank you all.

Comment: You probably want `DisplayMap.insert(DisplayMap.begin() + i, map[i])`, in this case, it's the the same thing as `DisplayMap.push_back(map[i])` because you are starting from zero and adding to the end.

Comment: Thanks @BarmakShemirani, it works. Another way was creating all the characters of the string to const char*.